# Perfect Forwarding for Lambda Chaining

Tags: c++, lambda, perfect-forwarding, boost-hana

I want to chain/compose multiple lambdas to a new lambda. When calling the new lambda with parameters it should call the original lambdas with these parameters. This lambda chaining does work well when the parameters are just copied but when I want to modify them **perfect forwarding** does not work:

```cpp
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <cassert>

constexpr auto chain_lambdas = [](auto... lambdas) {
    constexpr auto lambdasTpl = boost::hana::make_basic_tuple(lambdas...);

    return [lambdas(lambdasTpl)](auto&&... args) {
        auto argsTpl = boost::hana::make_basic_tuple(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);

        boost::hana::for_each(lambdas, [args(argsTpl)](auto lambda) mutable {
            boost::hana::unpack(std::move(args), [lambda(lambda)](auto&&... args) {
                lambda(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
            });
        });
    };
};


auto main() -> int
{
    auto lambda1 = [](bool& called){
        called = true;    
    };

    auto lambda2 =  [](bool& called){
        called = true;    
    };

    bool called = false;
    chain_lambdas(lambda1, lambda2)(called);

    assert(called == true);
    return 0;
}
```

Code at the [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Tvcv8x). Does perfect forwarding even work for this use case?

Comment: Calling multiple moved parameters is dangerous, for regular reference seems better than forwarding reference.

Comment: Well, removing the `std::move` will make the code code compile but it will not satisfy the `assert`. So parameters are not perfect forwarded?

Comment: I would do [that way](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c54b8e4c1a6308c2), for `lambda1(called), lambda2(called);`.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It works very well! I still don't understand whats the problem with my initial solution. The difference to my solution is that you don't capture the args. Maybe that did the trick.

Comment: `make_basic_tuple` does copy/move of your parameters. you would need [`std::forward_as_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple) (or boost equivalent).

Comment: What is the `[lambdas(lambdasTpl)]` meant to represent? There's no expansion, I'm just not used to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`auto argsTpl = boost::hana::make_basic_tuple(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);` does copy (move) of arguments, so you only mutate the copy.

You need `std::forward_as_tuple` equivalent for boost:

```
constexpr auto chain_lambdas = [](auto... lambdas) {
    constexpr auto lambdasTpl = boost::hana::make_basic_tuple(lambdas...);

    return [lambdas(lambdasTpl)](auto&&... args) {
        auto argsTpl = boost::hana::basic_tuple<decltype(args)...>(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);

        boost::hana::for_each(lambdas, [args(argsTpl)](auto lambda) mutable {
            boost::hana::unpack(args, [lambda(lambda)](auto&&... args) {
                lambda(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
            });
        });
    };
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e7jfeW)

On my side, only with std (C++17), you might do:

```
constexpr auto chain_lambdas = [](auto... lambdas) {
    return [=](auto&&... args) {
        return std::apply([&](auto... f){ (f(args...), ...); }, std::tie(lambdas...));
    };
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c54b8e4c1a6308c2).

I drop `std::forward` for `args` as calling function with moved object might be undesirable, but you can enable it if wanted.

Comment: What is `[lambdas(lambdasTpl)]` meant to represent? Edit - should have asked the author

Comment: Alternative style for `[lambdas = lambdasTpl]`, i.e [capture](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) with initializer (3) available since C++14.

Comment: I'm asking because it's variadic but `lambdas` is unexpanded. Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm just used to always needing the ellipsis somewhere. Is it like multiple assignment?

Comment: `lambdasTpl` is a (single) tuple, ellipsis are already be used to create it.

Comment: Ellipses were applied to `lambdas` once when creating `lambdasTpl` but not later, where the left hand side of `operator()` is an unexpanded variadic argument. The right hand side doesn't seem relevant to me. If you have `X... x` since when can you say `x(anything)`?

Comment: No, you have `auto var = f(x...); bar(var);`. Just see that I (OP first BTW) have shadowed name `lamdbas` :-/